# SideMenu black view

Tags: objective-c, ios, sidebar

I am trying to make a sidebar menu but i have a little problem.

I explain :

1. I created an UIViewController that i called sideMenuViewController
2. In my viewController Class (the initial view controller), in the header file, i import my class SideMenuViewController and i wrote :

   -(IBAction)openSideMenu:(id)sender;

   ```
   @property(nonatomic, retain) SideMenuViewController *sideMenu;
   ```

The openSideMenu action  is associated to the menu button.[image: Menu button]

I implemented this method like this :

```
- (IBAction)openSideMenu:(id)sender {
    CGRect destination = self.view.frame;

    if(destination.origin.x > 0){
        destination.origin.x = 0;
    }else{
        destination.origin.x += SideMenuX;
    }

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 animations:^{
        self.view.frame = destination;
    }completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        if(finished){

        }
    }];
}
```

SideMenuX is a macro : `#define SideMenuX 154.4`

My viewDidLoad method looks like this :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    _sideMenu = [[SideMenuViewController alloc] init];
    [self.view sendSubviewToBack:_sideMenu.view];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

**The problem is that when i click on the menu button, i get a black screen and not my side menu view.**

[image: Black screen side Bar Menu]

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two problems:

1. You are not adding the sideMenu at all. Try adding it to the parent view (`self.view.superview`), which in your case most likely will be the UIWindow:

   ```
    [self.view.superview insertSubview:_sideMenu.view belowSubview:self.view];
   ```

   If you are using a navigation controller, use `self.navigationController.view` instead `self.view`.
2. Not sure if you initialized the view with a NIB or the Storyboard (see below if you didn't).

---

Here is a [working example](https://github.com/j4n0/slidecontroller). I created the left view controller inside the storyboard like this:

- Throw a View Controller component on the storyboard.
- Select the controller on the left column, and go to the Identity Inspector on the right column (alt+cmd+3):

  - Set the Class to `SideMenuViewController`
  - Set the Storyboard ID to `SideMenuViewController`

Instantiate the controller inside viewDidLoad with

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
self.sideMenu = (SideMenuViewController*)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SideMenuViewController"];
```

then insert it as child of the superview.

---

**(Answering the comment below)**

This line is the problem:

```
[self.view.superview addSubview:_sideMenu.view];
```

In a NIB based project the superview is UIWindow, but in a Storyboard project, the self.view.superview of a UIViewController is nil. You can solve this, for example, adding a UINavigationViewController. Follow these steps:

- Throw in a "Navigation Controller"
- Delete the view controller it points to.
- Press Ctrl and drag the pointer from the UINavigationController to your view controller, and select "root view controller" on the dialog that appears.
- Drag the arrow pointing to your view controller to the UINavigationController (the one that marks the initial view controller, not the one that comes from UINavigationController).

Then change your code to

```
_sideMenu = [[SideMenuViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SideMenuViewController" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController.view.superview insertSubview:_sideMenu.view belowSubview:self.navigationController.view];
```

To hide the navigation bar of the UINavigationController, select it in the Storyboard and click Hidden in the Attributes Inspector (alt+cmd+4).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I added this line : `[self.view.superview insertSubview:_sideMenu.view belowSubview:self.view];` but it does not work :/

Comment: uhm maybe the SideMenuViewController lacks a NIB? Create one with File > New File > User Interface > Empty, name it SideMenuViewController, select the new SideMenuViewController.xib, click File's owner, go to Identity Inspector (alt+cmd 3) and set class to SideMenuViewController. Or you can create a definition in the Storyboard as I posted above. Or, you can create a sample project in github and post the address.

Comment: Thank you ! I used github project that you gave to implement my own class and it works !

Comment: I added the project on Github, I want to know why the application shows me a black page. This is the link : https://github.com/ali59a/SideMenuTest

Answer (score 0):

All you're seeing is black because you don't have the side menu view added. Try this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
      [super viewDidLoad];
      _sideMenu = [[SideMenuViewController alloc] init];
      [self.view addSubview:_sideMenu.view];
      [self.view sendSubviewToBack:_sideMenu.view];
}
```